# about infinitely many bounded prime gaps

Tags: real-analysis, number-theory, prime-numbers, prime-gaps, twin-primes

Let $p_n$ be the $n$'th prime $\alpha \in (0,1)$ and $e$ the euler constant. By mean value theorem one has: $$ e^{p_{n+1}^{\alpha}} =  e^{c_n^{\alpha}}\frac{\alpha}{c_n^{1 - \alpha}} \cdot (p_{n+1} - p_n) + e^{p_n^{\alpha}}$$ Supposes that $\exists N \in \mathbb{n}$ such that $\forall n \geq N$ one has $p_{n+1} - p_n > D \in \mathbb{R}_+$ then it comes out that 
$$ e^{p_{n+1}^{\alpha}} > \alpha \cdot D \cdot \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{e^{c_k^{\alpha}}}{c_k^{1 - \alpha}} + C > \alpha \cdot D \cdot \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{e^{p_k^{\alpha}}}{p_k^{1 - \alpha}} + C$$ where $C = -\alpha\cdot D\cdot\sum_{k=1}^N\frac{e^{c_k^{\alpha}}}{c_k^{1 - \alpha}} + e^{p_N^{\alpha}}$ is a constant. But one can see that $S_\alpha(p_n) = \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{e^{p_k^{\alpha}}}{p_k^{1 - \alpha}} = \sum_{k=1}^{p_n} \frac{e^{p_k^{\alpha}}}{p_k^{1 - \alpha}} (\pi(k) - \pi(k-1))$ Using summation by parts it can be obtained $$ S_\alpha(p_n) = e^{(p_n+1)^{\alpha}} \frac{\pi(p_n)}{(p_n+1)^{1-\alpha}} - \int_1^{p_n} \pi(x) \left( \frac{e^{x^{\alpha}}}{x^{1-\alpha}}\right)^\prime dx \sim \frac{e^{p_n^{\alpha}} p_n^\alpha}{\log(p_n)} $$ Therefore $$ e^{p_{n+1}^{\alpha} - p_n^{\alpha}} \geq \frac{p_n^{\alpha}}{\log(p_n)} \cdot \alpha D$$ But $p_{n+1}^{\alpha} - p_n^{\alpha} \sim \frac{p_{n+1} - p_n}{p_n^{1- \alpha}}\alpha < \frac{\alpha}{p_n^{1-\alpha-\theta}}$ for $\theta > 0.525$ hence upon taking logarithm $$ \alpha \geq p_n^{1-\alpha-\theta}( \alpha\log(p_n) - \log(\log(p_n) + \log(\alpha \cdot D))  $$ which is a contradiction for $1 - \alpha - \theta > 0$ Therefore there is a sequence such that $p_{n_k+1} - p_{n_k} < D$ for $D > 0$,  which is obviously not true ... where is the mistake ? Of course one can say that I cannot assume $p_{n+1} - p_n<2$ so it must be stated first $D \geq 3$ But any other mistakes?

Comment: If you want anyone to read your question, try to rephrase it. Right now it starts with an equation with five different variables/sequences of variables and almost no explanation and it only gets worse from there on. Even people who might know the answer will not bother to guess what every last of your $e,\alpha,p_n,c_n,C,D,\ldots$ stand for.

Comment: Thank you, for your suggestion